# Login error with php

Tags: php

I downloaded a script online for a basic system that will make a user login with  username of admin and password admin, 
But the script has a small error with the login page it seems there a variable that is not declared, I can see the variable is not declared from the form but I can’t declare in a way that can make it work. I need a way to declare the `$position` variable from form input, so it works well with login.php
Here is the error

> Notice: Undefined index: position in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\preenrolmentsystem\login.php on line 20

The source has 2 pages one for login.php And one for the form namely formform.php

here is the source for login.php

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Connect to mysql server
include('connect.php');

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$login = clean($_POST['id']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$position = clean($_POST['position']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $position = $row['position'];
    }
if ($position=='admin')
{
    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE idnum='$login' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
//  {
//  $level=$row['position'];
//  }
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
            session_write_close();
            //if ($level="admin"){
            header("location: admin/index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: loginform.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
if ($position=='student')
{
    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM prereg WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
//  {
//  $level=$row['position'];
//  }
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['idnumber'];
            session_write_close();
            //if ($level="admin"){
            header("location: student/profile.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: loginform.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
if ($position=='Casher')
{
    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM casher WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
//  {
//  $level=$row['position'];
//  }
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['idnumber'];
            session_write_close();
            //if ($level="admin"){
            header("location: casher/index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: loginform.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
if ($position=='teacher')
{
    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE idnumber='$login' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
//  {
//  $level=$row['position'];
//  }
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['idnumber'];
            session_write_close();
            //if ($level="admin"){
            header("location: teacher/index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: loginform.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
```

?>

and loginform.php

```
 <?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.ed{
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#00CCFF;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#button1{
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#00CCFF;
padding:5px;
background-color:#00CCFF;
height: 34px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/amuni.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="loginform.php">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="pre_reg.php">Student Pre Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="help.php">Help</a>
                </li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="padding:20px; text-align:justify; font-family:arial;">

        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        I.D. Number<br>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="ed"><br>
        Password<br>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="ed"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="button1">
        </form>
</div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

any input appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason why there isn't an input on the form for "position"? (Looking at the code it probably should be a drop down list with a multiple choice of values such as "admin", "student", "teacher" etc.)

Comment: @Lorax: those values appear to come from the user table. (Posted value is overwritten immediately.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something similar to:

```
if (isset($_POST['position'])) {
    //do something with position
    $position = clean($_POST['position']));
} else {
    //position was not set, maybe give it a default value and use that
    $position = null;
}
```

Comment: SanDange when you say do someting with position what do you mean?

Comment: @Lorax cn u give a sample